# Who is Rey's mother?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens*…

> Rey is drawn to Luke Skywalker’s lightsaber, which gives her an intense series of visions. She sees Luke being betrayed by Han’s son, causing Luke to leave. She then immediately sees herself as a little girl screaming for her father not to leave her.

This pretty clearly tells us that …

> Luke is her father. Especially since the movie ends with her reuniting with him.

So who is Rey’s mother?

Is there anything in the other movies or books about the identity of

> Luke’s wife?

Comment: Leia...­­­­­­­­

Comment: “She then immediately sees herself as a little girl screaming for her father not to leave her.” — Are we sure she’s screaming for her father? I thought she just said “Don’t go.”

Comment: @CandiedMango - flagged because ewwwwww! This is Star Wars, not [Crusader Knights II](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197675/is-marrying-my-own-sister-a-good-idea?lq=1). Oh... [wait....](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3013/did-leia-know-luke-was-her-brother-when-she-kissed-him)

Comment: @JakeGould - Midichlorians. The answer is **always** "midichlorians". Didn't Lucas teach you anything?

Comment: "Rey, **I** am your mother."

Comment: @randal'thor: LOL! :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, the canon that existed before that told the story of Luke and his wife, are no longer official canon. At this point there are multiple theories going around. One says Luke is her father, and that would possibly mean that Mara Jade was his wife. Another theory is that she was immaculately conceived by the force. Last theory I've seen is she doesn't have a connection to Luke other than being one of his padawan's at the point when Kylo Ren betrayed Luke.

Comment: So, basically, "I don't know"? :P

Comment: no one knows.... it's all theory. you're not going to get an answer on this until ep8 or ep9 most likely.

Comment: Now we wait. Only 524 days to go!

Answer (score -3):

Rey's mom will be revealed to be Captain Phasma, Luke's ex and perhaps one of the reasons the first order have light saber resistant weapons.

Comment: Is this just a guess?

Comment: It is based on the fact that why else whould they have drawn any attention to this character?  Not much in the movie. Also the trader who screams that the falcon is his is the same voice of the individual holding onto her hand in her vision of childhood.  Is there a reason why he owns the falcon and that she knows it inside out.  Kylo appears to know who she is - a cousin, no doubt as there would be no reason for him not to call out his sister.

Comment: It's gonna be great when this is proven true